# read all lines in text file with separator

Tags: c#, text-files, readline

I have a file with this content :

```
1,2,3,4,5#
1,2,3,4,5#
```

How can i read all lines  using `readline` ?the important thing is i need to separate the values in each line ,i mean the first line's values `1,2,3,4,5` should be separated .

Suppose i have an array named `myarray` that can save all values in first line :the array should be like this :

```
myarray[0]=1
myarray[1]=2
myarray[2]=3
myarray[3]=4
myarray[4]=5
```

I am so new in IO in c#

Best regards

Comment: [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: With .net you can use StreamReader class.  However,  this class only read windows crlf lines (\r\n)

Comment: [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What have you tried? Consider you have two problems: 1. read lines from a file ([`StreamReader.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be a good start) and then 2. parsing each line into fields.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using LINQ you can do:

```
List<string[]> list = File.ReadLines("YourFile.txt")
                          .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
                          .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                          .ToList();
```

- [`File.ReadLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) would read the file line by line.
- .`Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))` would remove the `#` from end of the
  line
- `.Select(line => line.Split(','))` would split the line on comma and return an array of string items.
- `ToList()` would give you a `List<string[]>` back.

You can also use `TrimEnd` and `Split` in a single `Select` statement like below, *(it would result in the same output)*:

```
List<string[]> list = File.ReadLines("YourFile.txt")
                          .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#').Split(','))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: @EhsanAkbar, change `"YourFile.txt"` to the file path you currently have.

Comment: I did that dear friend

Comment: @EA, There is some illegal character in the file path you have provided. What is the path you are providing to `File.ReadLines` ?

Comment: List<string[]> list = File.ReadLines("D:\a.txt")
                            .Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#'))
                            .Select(line => line.Split(','))
                            .ToList();

Comment: @EA, you have to escape back slash in the path, so either a double back slash like `"D:\\a.txt"` or `@"D:\a.txt"` should be fine.

Comment: @Habib you can shorten two  projections to one

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, yes that `.Select(r => r.TrimEnd('#').Split(','))` should do it, but would be harder to explain, IMO.

Comment: I don't think  so it's just trim and split a normal developer should get understand what's happening.:D

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, fair enough. added that as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

That will return an array of all the lines.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use a StreamReader to read all the lines in from a file and split them with a given delimiter (,).

```
var filename = @"C:\data.txt";
using (var sr = new StreamReader(filename))
{
    var contents = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var myarray = contents.
        Split(',');
}
```

Although I do prefer the LINQ approach answer further up.